# Remotely access Linux from Windows computers

Tags: networking, server, ssh, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I have an interesting situation. I work for a company that sells medical equipment. We work in many hospitals as a 3rd party, but one particular hospital, due to its nature, requires heavy restrictions. We have to use their computers and the software is very outdated, with no chance of installing other software.

What we want to do is simply use google apps via a browser. The browser they use is IE 8 or 9. We at IT have determined the reason why Calendar refuses to work is that the browser is too old.

The workaround I wanted to discuss is remote desktop connection. We currentyly use .rdp shortcuts to connect to our main server to use our medical software. I wanted to do the same thing on the server with Google Chrome, but the supervisor advised against it.

I have some old desktops, but not another copy of Windows Server. I want to use Ubuntu Server in its place. Can I have them remotely access the ubuntu server as simply and as painlessly as possible just to use Chrome?

Thank you for your help. I have very very little experience with Ubuntu and 0 with ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the windows version of Google Chrome (and it's subdirectories) on the server and just mount it using Samba, and run from there.  That way all clients would be running the same copy of Chrome, and they would all share data.

You would have to install it on Windows and copy the folder to the server, then share that server folder with samba, and mount it on the Windows machines as a samba share on bootup.  You should then be able to run it just fine.

Comment: Do you thibk this is doable in this situation? If I have to make any changes on the Windows side that invoke UAC, like install software, I'm barred due to the hospital's stringent security. Also, you mentioned sharing data. That's not necessary, perhaps- I might be able to convert another old desktop to run Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, everything would be accomplished by installing Google Chrome to the server folder.  You wouldn't have to do anything extra.  In fact, if you already have a copy of Google Chrome for Windows installed, you could just copy that folder to the server and share it.  That way you can run it over the network without having to worry about anything at all.  You shouldn't have to worry about UAC here, it should keep quiet (I have mine disabled.)